# Sort argparse help alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am using Python's (2.7) argparse facility and would like to automatically sort the help it produces alphabetically by option.

By default help entries are sorted in the order they are added*, as in:

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Load duration curves and other plots')
p.add_argument('--first', '-f', type=int, default=1, help='First Hour')
p.add_argument('--dur', '-d', type=int, default=-1, help='Duration in Hours. Use -1 for all')
p.add_argument('--title', '-t', help='Plot Title (for all plots), default=file name')
p.add_argument('--interp', '-i', action="store_true", default=True, 
                help='Use linear interpolation for smoother curves')
...
args = p.parse_args()
```

Which when called as `python script -h` produces:

```
usage: script.py [-h] [--first FIRST] [--dur DUR] [--title TITLE] [--interp]

Load duration curves and other plots

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --first FIRST, -f FIRST
                        First Hour
  --dur DUR, -d DUR     Duration in Hours. Use -1 for all
  --title TITLE, -t TITLE
                        Plot Title (for all plots), default=file name
  --interp, -i          Use linear interpolation for smoother curves
```

Is it possible to automatically sort them alphabetically instead? This would be dur, first, h, interp, title.

*Obviously the work around is to manually maintain by adding entries using p.add_argument in  alphabetical added order but I am trying to avoid doing so.

Comment: I think you can hook p.show_help or something  and manually parse the arg list ... I'll see if i can find the docs on it...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this by providing a custom [`HelpFormatter` class](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#formatter-class); the internals of which are officially undocumented. This means you are on your own when it comes to compatibility from Python version to version, but I find the interface quite stable:

```
from argparse import HelpFormatter
from operator import attrgetter

class SortingHelpFormatter(HelpFormatter):
    def add_arguments(self, actions):
        actions = sorted(actions, key=attrgetter('option_strings'))
        super(SortingHelpFormatter, self).add_arguments(actions)


p = argparse.ArgumentParser(...
    formatter_class=SortingHelpFormatter,
)
```

Here I sort on the option strings (`('--dur', '-d')`, etc.), but you could take your pick as to what you want to sort on. This simple sorting option puts the single-dash options last, like the `-h` option.

which outputs:

```
usage: [-h] [--first FIRST] [--dur DUR] [--title TITLE] [--interp]

Load duration curves and other plots

optional arguments:
  --dur DUR, -d DUR     Duration in Hours. Use -1 for all
  --first FIRST, -f FIRST
                        First Hour
  --interp, -i          Use linear interpolation for smoother curves
  --title TITLE, -t TITLE
                        Plot Title (for all plots), default=file name
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
```

Comment: ``super(HelpFormatter`` should be ``super(SortingHelpFormatter``

Comment: Is the call to add_argument (singular) ever used?

Comment: @grieve: Yes, it is used by the `HelpFormatter.add_arguments()` method that I overrode.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well that makes sense. Just wondering if the undocumented API ever bypasses add_arguments in favor of add_argument.

Comment: @grieve: *Currently*, it doesn't.

Comment: Why does `help` always end up last?  It doesn't in my solution and I would have expected them to be roughly equivalent ...

Comment: The explanation was clear enough.  I should have picked up on it.  I like sorting on `dest` better than on `option_strings`, but I suppose that's completely arbitrary ... Do you mess around with the internals of argparse frequently?  It took me quite a while digging around in there to come up with a solution that isn't as nice as yours ...  Also, are you aware of any plans to ever expose these features in the API?  Since it's pure python, I wouldn't think that other python implementations doing it differently would be a significant problem ...

Comment: @mgilson: No, I don't mess about in it frequently, but I have picked up the general structure from previous forays. I have no idea about the future plans for the module.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the ArgumentParser class you can pass in a help formatter:
http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#formatter-class

So apparently you can use one of the supplied formatters, but cannot override and replace them without reverse engineering a bit:

```
>>> h = argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
>>> print h.__doc__
Help message formatter which adds default values to argument help.

    Only the name of this class is considered a public API. All the methods
    provided by the class are considered an implementation detail.
```

Comment: I have often thought that more of this should be exposed to the user :-/ (other than providing a few formatters and essentially not allowing the user to mess with them in any way) -- I think it's because the code is pretty ugly and difficult to write and the argparse devs didn't want to subject the user to that.

Comment: Which is ironic, since `argparse` was motivated by the ugliness and difficulty of extending the `optparse` codebase.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, *definitely* more ugly way to do it than proposed by @MartijnPieters:

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()

#add arguements here

for g in p._action_groups:
    g._group_actions.sort(key=lambda x:x.dest)
```

It may be nice to put this in a `try`/`except` clause as it's only formatting help, therefore it shouldn't really matter for the execution of the program if this piece of code fails on an `AttributeError` or something ...

Comment: That's something I also thought about and seemed to work. But I wasn't comfortable suggesting that because we can't easily tell what side effects changing the order of `p._group_actions` could have. What about the action groups in `p._actions`? Might the order in those be linked in some way to this one and needs to be changed as well? So no upvote for the answer, but a mental +1 for digging up the code and hack value ;-)

Comment: @LukasGraf -- I won't **guarantee** this solution won't mess up things, but I *think* it's pretty safe.  Everything seems to be parsed out using dictionaries which are unordered anyway (It seems to me that the order is only kept for the purpose of formatting the help message).  I tried sorting `p._actions`, but that doesn't seem to have any effect...

Comment: If all you want to change is the order of the help lines, then sorting the `_group_actions` lists is logical.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to @mgilson's answer. I thought I had posted this earlier, but apparently not.

```
d = dict()
d['--first'] = ('-f', "type=int", "default=1", "help='First Hour'")
d['--dur'] = ('-d', type=int, default=-1, help='Duration in Hours. Use -1 for all')
# etc

for prim_option in sorted(d):
    p.add_arguments(prim_option, *d[prim_option])
```

You can adjust what exactly is used as the key in the dictionary, as well as the arguments to `sorted` and the exact structure of the call to `add_arguments`, to get the desired sorting order. This adheres to the publicly documented interface of `argparse`, but does add a layer to the process of defining your parser. (Depending on your philosophy, such separation of information about the options from the implementation of the parser might be a good thing.)

Answer (score 1):

The order of arguments in the help is determined by the `parser.format_help` method:

```
Definition:  parser.format_help(self)
Source:
    def format_help(self):
        formatter = self._get_formatter()
        ...
        # positionals, optionals and user-defined groups
        for action_group in self._action_groups:
            formatter.start_section(action_group.title)
            formatter.add_text(action_group.description)
            formatter.add_arguments(action_group._group_actions)
            formatter.end_section()
```

`help` is created by fetching an `formatter` object, and then adding 'sections' to it.  Here it loops through the `_action_groups`, putting each in its own section, and adding its actions (arguments) with the `add_arguments` method.  The formatter is temporary, existing only to create a strings (usually multiple lines).

Action groups include the default `postionals` and `optionals`, plus any the the user creates.  These groups are only used for help, not for parsing.  So the `action_group._group_actions` list could be reordered without affecting parsing. (the parser has its own list of actions, `parser._actions`).

This confirms @mgilson's observation that sorting `p._actions` does not affect the help, but sorting the `_group_actions` does.

Sorting `_actions` will affect the `usage` (whether part of help or standalone):

```
    # usage
    formatter.add_usage(self.usage, self._actions,
                        self._mutually_exclusive_groups)
```

Note that `action_groups` are not passed to the usage section.  The usage section does reorder its actions, displaying `optionals` first, then `positionals`.

Sort arguments before/during the `add_argument` stage if you want to control parsing order of positionals, and their order in the usage.

If you just want to control order in the help groups, then feel free to reorder things in the `._group_actions` list, either before calling the formatter, or within it.

There have been other SO questions about controlling the order of actions in the `usage`.  Some, for example, don't want the `positionals` ordered after `optionals`.

I agree that the Formatter class is cumbersom.  But it is, for the most part, separate from the Parser class.  So it could be rewritten with minimal effect on parsing.  The existing Formatter subclasses just tweak low level methods, ones that control line wrapping and help line formating.  The significant interface between parser and formatter are the `format_usage` and `format_help` methods, which are relatively simpler and highlevel.

## subclassing

Despite the warning that @grieve quotes, people do subclass the `HelpFormatter` to suit their own needs.  The only thing keeping people from doing so is some sort of company policy.  All the warning tells us is that the argparse developers have not tried to imagine or document all the changes that users might want to make.  I couldn't even enumerate the ones that I've suggested over the past several years.