# Argparse subcommand order in help output

Tags: python, argparse

Using Python's `argparse` module, is there a way to order sub-commands created through the use of subparsers in the help output?

Comment: looks like duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268602/sort-argparse-help-alphabetically

Comment: The question you linked to is about the order of arguments. I need to sort the sub-commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found a way using `argparse.HelpFormatter`.

```
class CustomHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def _iter_indented_subactions(self, action):
        try:
            get_subactions = action._get_subactions
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            self._indent()
            if isinstance(action, argparse._SubParsersAction):
                for subaction in sorted(get_subactions(), key=lambda x: x.dest):
                    yield subaction
            else:
                for subaction in get_subactions():
                    yield subaction
            self._dedent()
```